# How to make NavigationViewItem content vertical?

Tags: uwp-xaml, winui-3

By default the NavigationViewItem content (icon and text) is arranged horizontally:

[image: default NavigationViewItem]

I would like to arrange the icon and text vertically like the Windows Store does:

[image: Microsoft Store NavigationViewItem]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make NavigationViewItem content vertical?

Windows Store app's navigationview is custom navigationview base on [SplitView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview?view=winrt-22000). And the items part rendered with listview. you could custom the item content layout as requirement.

And if you do want to implement it base on WinUI NavigationView, we suggest your use DataTemplate to replace the default `NavigationViewItem`.

For example

```
<NavigationView
    x:Name="Nav"
    CompactPaneLength="60"
    Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded">
    <NavigationView.MenuItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0" />
        </Style>
    </NavigationView.MenuItemContainerStyle>
    <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <SymbolIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" Symbol="Send" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Send" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you Nico Zhu!